# Lightning modal file previewer

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So I was using the `lightning:openFiles` event to allow users to preview, update and download their files. However, the Saleforce docs are not happy about this:

> The lightning:openFiles event is no longer recommended. Use the Lightning navigation service instead. Application event used to open one or more file records. This event triggers a modal file previewer or download depending on the form factor. [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:openFiles/documentation)

It looks like `lightning:navigation` will take the user out of my app to another page, not something I want. I want to leave the user in the app but allow them to manipulate their files. Exactly how you would do it from the Files related list on any Salesforce object inside the standard Salesforce.
So how do I use the `lightning:navigation` to do the same thing?